# Mongoose/MongoDB: Get second to last document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

How would I be able to get the 2nd to latest or previous day's document collection using Mongoose?

my code to get the latest data goes as follows:

```
data.findOne()
        .sort({"_id": -1})
        .exec(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error getting data..');
            } 
            if (data) {
                res.json(data);
            }
            else {
                console.log('No data found!');
            }
        });
```

This only returns the LATEST document in the collection. I instead need the one prior to the latest one, so one from a day before this one, how would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is the fix I used to make it work for what I wanted, hope it helps others:

I decided to import MomentJS, from there it displays the current date, subtracting 1 from it, to display the previous date's value, hence giving me the proper collection from the day before.

Code:

```
const moment = require('moment');

...

data.find({"updated": moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('L')}) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Then you'd have to use aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
  { $sort: {"date": -1}}, // sort by latest date (descending)
  { $limit: 2}, // limit to the first two results
  { $sort: {"date": 1}}, // sort these two ascending
  { $limit: 1} // get first document
])
```

This pipeline is translated in mongoose like that (I think):

```
data.aggregate([
      { $sort: {"date": -1}},
      { $limit: 2},
      { $sort: {"date": 1}},
      { $limit: 1}
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
```

Also by sorting without adding a `$match` pipeline, your first `$sort` would sort all the documents in your collection. So if your collection is big you might want to restrict them with some query parameters that you can add to the `$match` pipeline. You could add the match before the first `$sort`

E.g.

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
  { $match: {...}},
  { $sort: {"date": -1}},
  { $limit: 2},
  { $sort: {"date": 1}},
  { $limit: 1}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the 2nd before the last

```
data.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1).skip(2).exec(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error getting data..');
            } 
            if (data) {
                res.json(data);
            }
            else {
                console.log('No data found!');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do like this:

```
data
.find()
.limit(2)
.sort({ "_id": -1 })
.exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json(data);
});
```

this will find on all documents sorted by id: -1, and then limit the result to two, this should give you the result that you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, this actually gave me the last 2 data, I only need the one prior to the latest one... For instance, today is 11/17/17 = latest, I need 11/16/17 = 2nd to latest